# Why header is automatically skipped in output file

Tags: hadoop, apache-pig

I want to storage my data **without** skipping data header

This is my pig script :

```
CRE_GM05 = LOAD '$input1' USING  PigStorage(;) AS (MGM_COMPTEUR:chararray,CIA_CD_CRV_CIA:chararray,CIA_DA_EM_CRV:chararray,CIA_CD_CTRL_BLCE:chararray,CIA_IDC_EXTR_RDJ:chararray,CIA_VLR_IDT_CRV_LOQ:chararray,CIA_VLR_REF_CRV:chararray,CIA_NO_SEQ_CRV:chararray,CIA_VLR_LG_ZON_RTG:chararray,CIA_HEU_CIA:chararray,CIA_TM_STP_CRE:chararray,CIA_CD_SI:chararray,CIA_VLR_1:chararray,CIA_DA_ARR_FIC:chararray,CIA_TY_ENR:chararray,CIA_CD_BTE:chararray,CIA_CD_PER:chararray,CIA_CD_EFS:chararray,CIA_CD_ETA_VAL_CRV:chararray,CIA_CD_EVE_CPR:int,CIA_CD_APLI_TDU:chararray,CIA_CD_STE_RTG:chararray,CIA_DA_TT_RTG:chararray,CIA_NO_ENR_RTG:chararray,CIA_DA_VAL_EVE:chararray,T32_001:chararray,TEC_013:chararray,TEC_014:chararray,DAT_001_X:chararray,DAT_002_X:chararray,TEC_001:chararray);
CRE_GM11 = LOAD '$input2' USING  PigStorage(;) AS (MGM_COMPTEUR:chararray,CIA_CD_CRV_CIA:chararray,CIA_DA_EM_CRV:chararray,CIA_CD_CTRL_BLCE:chararray,CIA_IDC_EXTR_RDJ:chararray,CIA_VLR_IDT_CRV_LOQ:chararray,CIA_VLR_REF_CRV:chararray,CIA_NO_SEQ_CRV:chararray,CIA_VLR_LG_ZON_RTG:chararray,CIA_HEU_CIA:chararray,CIA_TM_STP_CRE:chararray,CIA_CD_SI:chararray,CIA_VLR_1:chararray,CIA_DA_ARR_FIC:chararray,CIA_TY_ENR:chararray,CIA_CD_BTE:chararray,CIA_CD_PER:chararray,CIA_CD_EFS:chararray,CIA_CD_ETA_VAL_CRV:chararray,CIA_CD_EVE_CPR:int,CIA_CD_APLI_TDU:chararray,CIA_CD_STE_RTG:chararray,CIA_DA_TT_RTG:chararray,CIA_NO_ENR_RTG:chararray,CIA_DA_VAL_EVE:chararray,DAT_001_X:chararray,DAT_002_X:chararray,D08_001:chararray,PSE_001:chararray,PSE_002:chararray,PSE_003:chararray,RUB_001:chararray,RUB_002:chararray,RUB_003:chararray,RUB_004:chararray,RUB_005:chararray,RUB_006:chararray,RUB_007:chararray,RUB_008:chararray,RUB_009:chararray,RUB_010:chararray,TEC_001:chararray,TEC_002:chararray,TEC_003:chararray,TX_001_VLR:chararray,TX_001_DCM:chararray,D08_004:chararray,D11_004:chararray,RUB_016:chararray,T03_001:chararray);


-- Effectuer une jointure entre les deux tables

JOINED_TABLES = JOIN CRE_GM05 BY TEC_001, CRE_GM11 BY TEC_001;

-- Generer les colonnes 

DATA_GM05 = FOREACH JOINED_TABLES GENERATE 
        CRE_GM05::MGM_COMPTEUR  AS MGM_COMPTEUR,
        CRE_GM05::CIA_CD_CRV_CIA  AS CIA_CD_CRV_CIA,
        CRE_GM05::CIA_DA_EM_CRV   AS CIA_DA_EM_CRV,
        CRE_GM05::CIA_CD_CTRL_BLCE AS CIA_CD_CTRL_BLCE,
        CRE_GM05::CIA_IDC_EXTR_RDJ  AS CIA_IDC_EXTR_RDJ,
        CRE_GM05::CIA_VLR_IDT_CRV_LOQ AS CIA_VLR_IDT_CRV_LOQ,
        CRE_GM05::CIA_VLR_REF_CRV  AS CIA_VLR_REF_CRV,
        CRE_GM05::CIA_VLR_LG_ZON_RTG  AS CIA_VLR_LG_ZON_RTG,
        CRE_GM05::CIA_HEU_CIA AS CIA_HEU_CIA,
        CRE_GM05::CIA_TM_STP_CRE AS CIA_TM_STP_CRE,
        CRE_GM05::CIA_VLR_1 AS CIA_VLR_1,
        CRE_GM05::CIA_DA_ARR_FIC AS CIA_DA_ARR_FIC,
        CRE_GM05::CIA_TY_ENR AS CIA_TY_ENR,
        CRE_GM05::CIA_CD_BTE AS CIA_CD_BTE,
        CRE_GM05::CIA_CD_PER AS CIA_CD_PER,
        CRE_GM05::CIA_CD_EFS AS CIA_CD_EFS,
        CRE_GM05::CIA_CD_ETA_VAL_CRV AS CIA_CD_ETA_VAL_CRV,
        CRE_GM05::CIA_CD_EVE_CPR AS CIA_CD_EVE_CPR,
        CRE_GM05::CIA_CD_APLI_TDU AS CIA_CD_APLI_TDU,
        CRE_GM05::CIA_CD_STE_RTG AS CIA_CD_STE_RTG,
        CRE_GM05::CIA_DA_TT_RTG AS CIA_DA_TT_RTG,
        CRE_GM05::CIA_NO_ENR_RTG AS CIA_NO_ENR_RTG,
        CRE_GM05::CIA_DA_VAL_EVE AS CIA_DA_VAL_EVE,
        CRE_GM05::T32_001 AS T32_001,
        CRE_GM05::TEC_013 AS TEC_013,
        CRE_GM05::TEC_014 AS TEC_014,
        CRE_GM05::DAT_001_X AS DAT_001_X,
        CRE_GM05::DAT_002_X AS DAT_002_X,
        CRE_GM05::TEC_001 AS TEC_001;

STORE DATA_GM05 INTO '$OUTPUT_FILE' USING PigStorage(';');
```

It returns data but I lost the first line of headers !

**Note** that my $input1 and $input2 variables are csv files

I tried using CSVLoader but it doesn't working also.

I need to get output stored with headers please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In pig final output by default there is no headers coming. Also adding header to final output will doesn't make any sense as sequence of rows is not fixed in pig output.

If you want to add header to final output, either merge all the part files data to a file in local file system where you can add header information explicitly or use hive table to store the output of this pig script. There is HCatlog store can be used for same.